# MacRuby gem signature is invalide

Tags: xcode, rubygems, macruby

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 and MacRuby 0.12.
I need to use the Spreadsheet gem, but I keep having a "signature" issue when I try to execute my program :

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.5/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:372:in `validate!': OLE2 signature is invalid (Ole::Storage::FormatError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.5/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:364:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.5/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:105:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.5/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:72:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/ruby-ole-1.2.11.5/lib/ole/storage/base.rb:78:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:1179:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:121:in `read'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/workbook.rb:32:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:62:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/MacRuby/0.13/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:68:in `open'
```

Is the OLE gem compatible with MacRuby? What are my options here?

Thanks for your help.